# Format Javascript in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way or a VS add-on to format Javascript in the text editor? Like properly indent each line, align the braces, ... etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple just use Ctrl + K + D for Javascript formatting and use Ctrl + A + K + F for formatting your c#, vb code

Enjoy coding with shortcut's  :-)

Comment: CRTL-K-D will also do style sheets.

Comment: Format selection from the context menu also works. I thought it did html tags only but one has to select the js separately.

Answer (score 2):

Inside VS , you have Edit-Advanced-Format Document, also goto options select editors and then Javascript/HTML and select/deselect desired options